# Coil rememberAsyncImagePainter states are not updated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I use `Coil` along with `Compose`.

And I'm trying to make a shimmer animation while the image is loading.
All examples use `ImagePainter` with `ImagePainter.State` and it works correctly, but this is now marked as "deprecated".
That's why I chose `AsyncImagePainter`. Without the state check it works perfect, but with the check I get an **infinite shimmer animation**.
I also tried to change the load state var with mutableState in the onSuccess method in `AsyncImagePainter`, but the animation is still **infinite**

```
@Composable
fun FoodItem(food: Fun) {
    Column (
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
    ) {
        val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(food.image.sm)
        if (painter.state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Loading) {
            AnimatedShimmer { ShimmerFoodItem(brush = it) }
        } else {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(104.dp)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(size = 8.dp)),
                painter = painter,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                contentDescription = "Food photo"
            )
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 4.dp),
                text = food.title,
                fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.body1.fontSize,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                maxLines = 1,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
            )
            Text(
                text = food.subtitle,
                fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle2.fontSize,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                maxLines = 2,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to provide size using

```
model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
    .data(overlayImage)
    .size(coil.size.Size.ORIGINAL) // Set the target size to load the image at.
    .build()
```

If you comment the line size is you will see that it gets stuck at loading state. Also you can provide any dimensions you want image to be loaded for instance 1280x720 with `.size(coil.size.Size(1280, 720))`

```
@Composable
private fun CoilSample() {
    val overlayImage =
        "https://images6.alphacoders.com/488/thumb-1920-488158.jpg"

    val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .data(overlayImage)
            .size(coil.size.Size.ORIGINAL) // Set the target size to load the image at.
            .build()
    )

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        Text("state:${painter.state}")

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            if (painter.state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Loading) {
                CircularProgressIndicator()
            } else {
                Image(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(104.dp)
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(size = 8.dp)),
                    painter = painter,
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    contentDescription = "photo"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also check out this answer as well if you need to get `Bitmap` or `ImageBitmap` from painter of Coil

[Get bitmap before using in a Composable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74684679/get-bitmap-before-using-in-a-composable/74686650#74686650)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it, including showing a holder icon when the state has an error, for example, if the image URL is invalid. The painter is supplied into the Composable immediately, but I added another state **showImage** that is initially true and can change whenever the ImageLoadingState Changes. You can wrap this whole code inside a function that accepts the URL parameter and will only show one Composable depending on the State of ShowImage/Loading/Error:

```
val modifier = Modifier
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(CornerSize(10.dp)))
            .padding(4.dp)

val url = "your_image_url_or_not"

val imagePainter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
    model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
      .data(url)
      .crossfade(true)
      .build(),
  )

val showImage = remember {
    mutableStateOf(true)
  }
 if (showImage.value) {
    Image(
      painter = imagePainter,
      contentDescription = description,
      contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
      modifier = modifier.padding(3.dp),
    )
  }

  if (imagePainter.state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Loading) {
    showImage.value = false
    CircularProgressIndicator(
      modifier = modifier,
      strokeWidth = 2.dp,
      color = MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant
    )
  } else if (imagePainter.state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Error) {
    showImage.value = false
    Icon(
      imageVector = Icons.Default.Person,
      contentDescription = description,
      modifier = modifier,
      tint = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
    )
  } else {
    showImage.value = true
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the `painter` needs to be supplied into an `Image` composable right away so its state could change, I tried implementing your use-case, and logged the `painter.state` it wouldn't get updated unless its supplied immediately on an `Image`, so I ended up with this

```
// random public image
val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
    model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
        .data("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQUJ0jVyT2UJwn_Ln5s4yd17MtwLlgzm8-WTGKExqZg&s")
        .build()
)

Box {

    Image(
        modifier = Modifier.size(150.dp),
        painter = painter,
        contentDescription = ""
    )

    runBlocking {
        delay(500)
    }

    if (painter.state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Loading) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(150.dp)
                .background(Color.Red)
        )
    }
}
```

Based on the [Coil](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/) Samples

Please don't mind the `runbBlocking` and the red `Box`, I just put them there to mimic something on top of the `Image` (shimmering) and to delay the showing of the actual `Image`(fetching). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this helped solve my problem. But now the images are loading so fast that the shimmer of the item doesn't even have time to draw :)